# Why java does not compare accurately large value at its upper range?

Tags: java, logic

for  input value of x = 200000000 and y = 20000000000000000, x and y lines will hold equal values after input(x^2 will be equal to 2*y), but on comparing these it prints NO i.e. x==y is false.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = scn.nextInt();
    Long x = (long)Math.pow(scn.nextLong(),2);
    Long y = 2*scn.nextLong();
    System.out.println((x==y)?"YES":"NO");
}
```

Meanwhile, if I

```
System.out.println((x-y==0)?"YES":"NO");
```

It prints YES.
So why it is happening?

Comment: Mainly because `(x-y==0)` is `0 == 0` which is working in an `int` (or `long`, I'm not sure, but it's not really relevant) context. `x==y`, on the other hand, is comparing two references (both values are `Long`s, i.e. objects, not `long`s, which would work).

Comment: okay got it. subtracting is using values while == will compare the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is auto boxing.

```
Long x = (long)Math.pow(scn.nextLong(),2);
Long y = 2*scn.nextLong();
```

x and y are Objects of type Long

either use Object equality test

```
System.out.println(x.equals(y)?"YES":"NO");
```

or use primitives

```
long x = (long)Math.pow(scn.nextLong(),2);
long y = 2*scn.nextLong();
System.out.println((x==y)?"YES":"NO");
```